# replace laptop hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have bought a ACER Aspire 5736Z-4790 laptop for my parents. It just passed the warranty. I think the hard disk is bad now. I cannot open/copy some of my files. It will crash (blue screen) when I do chkdsk /f/r in the stage 4 of 5 which is verifying file data. I can hear a strange noise when it is reading the bad sectors (I guess because it hangs there.)

I am thinking replace the hard disk. should I buy the same hard disk or any SATA laptop hard disk will be ok?

BTW, is there a way to repair it (with software)?

Answer (score 6):

Any 2.5inch sata hard disk would work, with some caveats. The *standard* hard drive thickness is 9mm. Some systems use 7mm drives. You could install a 7mm drive in a 9mm socket with a shim, but not vice versa.

If its physical damage and makes funny noises, its probably not repairable. Some people seem to think that [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) might do the trick with some sorts of damage, but i've not tried it myself, and i don't entirely understand the science behind the process it uses.

I'd also suggest checking with the hard drive manufacturer and Acer if there's a separate warranty for the hard drive - iirc the standard laptop warranty is 1 year, drives seem to have 3 year warranty

Comment: There is also 12.5mm 2.5" drives, 1tb. OEM drives have no warranty from the manufacturer.